# SwiftUI - ObservedObject is never deallocated

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

My app is leaking model objects because it the objects are keeping closures that are retaining the view itself.
It's better to show by an example.
In the code below, `Model` is not deallocated after the `ContentView` disappears.

```
//
// Content View is an owner of `Model`
// It passes it to `ViewB`
//
// When button is tapped, ContentView executes action
// assigned to Model by the ViewB
//
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                model.action?()
            }) {
                Text("Tap")
            }
            ViewB(model: model)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .onDisappear {
            print("CONTENT DISAPPEAR")
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.red.frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .onAppear {
//
// DANGER:
// Assigning this makes a leak and Model is never deallocated.
// This is because the closure is retaining 'self'
// But since it's a struct, how can we break the cycle here?
//
                model.action = { bAction() }
            }
    }
    
    private func bAction() {
        print("Hey!")
    }
    
}


class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    var action: (() -> Void)?
    
    deinit {
        print("MODEL DEINIT")
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why there's some kind of retain cycle occurring here.
Since View is a struct, referencing it in a closure should be safe, right?

Comment: I would make the model an optional and an `@ObservedObject` instead of a state object. I think that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ahoy @msmialko, while I can't give much reasoning for what I've observed, hopefully this will be a step in the right direction.

I decided to remove SwiftUI's memory management from the equation and tested with simple value and reference types:

```swift
private func doMemoryTest() {
  struct ContentView {
    let model: Model

    func pressButton() {
      model.action?()
    }
  }

  struct ViewB {
    let model: Model

    func onAppear() {
      model.action = action
      // { [weak model] in
      //   model?.action = action
      // }()
    }

    func onDisappear() {
      print("on ViewB's disappear")
      model.action = nil
    }

    private func action() {
      print("Hey!")
    }
  }

  class Model {
    var action: (() -> Void)?
    deinit {
      print("*** DEALLOCATING MODEL")
    }
  }


  var contentView: ContentView? = .init(model: Model())
  var viewB: ViewB? = .init(model: contentView!.model)

  contentView?.pressButton()

  viewB?.onAppear()
  contentView?.pressButton()

  // viewB?.onDisappear()
  print("Will remove ViewB's reference")
  viewB = nil
  print("Removed ViewB's reference")

  contentView?.pressButton()

  print("Will remove ContentView's reference")
  contentView = nil
  print("Removed ContentView's reference")
}
```

When I ran the code above, this was the console output (no deallocation of Model, as you observed):

```
Hey!
Will remove ViewB's reference
Removed ViewB's reference
Hey!
Will remove ContentView's reference
Removed ContentView's reference
```

In the above example it looks like I'm in complete control of the reference count on `Model`, however when I inspected the memory graph in Xcode, I could confirm that `Model` was retaining itself via `action.context` (I'm not sure what that means):

[image: Model's retain cycle1]

To fix the retain cycle with minimal changes, you might want to consider removing Model's action assignment using `ViewB.onDisappear` as I've done in my example. When I uncommented `viewB?.onDisappear()` then I saw the following console output:

```
Hey!
on ViewB's disappear
Will remove ViewB's reference
Removed ViewB's reference
Will remove ContentView's reference
*** DEALLOCATING MODEL
Removed ContentView's reference
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`Model` is not a struct, it is an `ObservableObject` which is of type `AnyObject` which is an `Object`

you should apply weak to in the capture list for .onAppear

```
.onAppear { [weak model] }
```

I *think* you could also just capture model incase its self that the issue is on

```
.onAppear { [model] }
```

Comment: It's not helping unfortunately. Note that the problem is in capturing `self` in the block assigned to `model.action`. Capturing model in `onAppear` is fine and doesn't lead to leaks.